# Recovering from a build-breaking self-mutation step in a CDK pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Suppose that we have a toy CDK pipeline as defined in the [CDK Typescript Workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/200-pipelines/5000-test-actions.html). Now, imagine we push in a change that will break the build. For instance, this could be a command in the synth step that requires a certain level of test coverage that is not met by our unit tests. When this change is pushed, the build executes fine, the pipeline is mutated, and the next invocation of the build will fail.

Even if we now reverted the commit that introduced this build breaking change, the pipeline will not finish as the build is broken and the self-mutation step fixing it will never be reached.

One way to recover from this is to destroy the pipeline and redeploy it. However, this is rather cumbersome if the pipeline is deploying some stack as it may entail various manual configuration and/or downtime.

Is there a better solution to recover from such situations and somehow force a self-mutation step first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is to deploy a working version manually using `cdk deploy` locally. Note that you don't have to destroy the pipeline to do this - `cdk deploy` will simply do what the Self-mutate step does and update the pipeline. It will not affect the stacks that the pipeline is deploying.

Make sure to push the change to git first so that the pipeline does not pull the non-working version and self-mutate back to a broken state.